# Largest order element of $\mathbb{Z}_{36} \times \mathbb{Z}_{40} \times \mathbb{Z}_{42}$ and how many?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm currently studying for a qualifying exam, and came across this question here:

[image]

I'm pretty stumped on what to do here, but I attempted an argument (which I believe is very wrong) as follows: I know $G$ isn't cyclic, so there aren't any elements of order $36 \cdot 40 \cdot 42$, so hoping to get the next largest, I computed $|(1,1,1)| = \text{lcm}(36,40,42) $ (which I believe to be wrong since I know that $|ab| \neq \text{lcm}(|a|,|b|)$ in general abelian groups).

From there, I tried to count the total number of all elements that would have this order using the fact that $a^k \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if $\text{gcd}(k,n)=1$.  So, letting $\phi$ be the Euler totient function, I counted $2304 = \phi(36) \cdot \phi(40) \cdot \phi(42)$ elements of order $|(1,1,1)|$ by finding all possible triples $(x,y,z) \in G$ such that $x,y,z$ are generators for $\mathbb{Z}_{36}, \mathbb{Z}_{40}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{42}$ respectively.

So obviously this result is hinging on a potentially incorrect assumption about the order of $(1,1,1)$.  The only reason I thought this *might* work is that $|(1,1,1)|$ seemed to be the $\text{lcm}(36,40,42)$ simply due to $1$ generating each respective group in the direct product.

I'd really appreciate some help on this problem, and where I went wrong.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what the primary decomposition of a finite abelian group is? If you can write $G$ in that form, finding the largest order becomes much easier. (Invariant factor decomposition makes the largest order super-easy, but one step at a time.)

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Bbb Z_{36}×\Bbb Z_{40}×\Bbb Z_{42}\cong\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_{12}×\Bbb Z_{2520}.$$

Thus the greatest order of an element is $2520.$

And there are $$2×12×\varphi (2520)=24×576=13824$$ of them.

---

Or, you can carefully count allowable triples $(i,j,k)$ such that $(a^i,b^j,c^k)$ will work,  where $a,b,c$ are generators of $\Bbb Z_{36},\Bbb Z_{40},\Bbb Z_{42}.$

I got $$(\varphi (36)+12) \varphi (40)(\varphi (42)+24)=13824.$$

Comment: So it seems I got the correct highest order of elements, but I counted too few.  Why did you add 12 and 24 in the below product?  I thought it would be phi(36)*phi(40)*phi(42) since that would be the total number of possible triple (x,y,z) where x,y,Z are generators?

Comment: Yes you did.   It's ok if the greatest common divisors $(i,36)=2,4$ and $(k,42)=2,3,$ which gives more. For instance there's $12$ numbers $i$ between $1$ and $36$ with $(i,36)=2,4.$  I over-counted at first,  forgetting that multiples of $3$ need to be excluded.  I almost nixed this second method,  but it actually works. You just have to be careful with your counting.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical form of the abelian group in terms of its invariants is $Z_2\times Z_{12} \times Z_{2520}$. LCM 2520 can occur iff we take an element of order 2520 in the third invariant. Hence the number of elements of order 2520 is $2*12*\phi(2520)$ =13824.